sqflite - get data with foreign key relation
I have 3 dart classes:
class Stock {
  final int? id;
  final String? name;
  final String? timestamp;

  Stock({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.timestamp,
  });

  factory Stock.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Stock(
    id: json['id'],
    name: json['name'],
    timestamp: json['timestamp'],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id' : id,
      'name' : name,
      'timestamp' : timestamp,
    };
  }
}

class Product {
  final int? id;
  final int? barcode;
  final String? name;
  final String? timestamp;

  Product({
    this.id,
    this.barcode,
    this.name,
    this.timestamp,
  });

  factory Product.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Product(
    id: json['id'],
    barcode: json['barcode'],
    name: json['name'],
    timestamp: json['timestamp'],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id' : id,
      'barcode' : barcode,
      'name' : name,
      'timestamp' : timestamp,
    };
  }
}

import 'package:stock_manager/model/product.dart';
import 'package:stock_manager/model/stock.dart';

class StockProduct {
  final int? id;
  final Stock stock;
  final Product product;
  final int cnt;
  final int del;
  final String timestamp;

  StockProduct({
    this.id,
    required this.stock,
    required this.product,
    required this.cnt,
    required this.del,
    required this.timestamp,
  });

  factory StockProduct.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => StockProduct(
    id: json['id'],
    stock: Stock.fromMap(json['stock_id']),
    product: Product.fromMap(json['product_id']),
    cnt: json['cnt'],
    del: json['del'],
    timestamp: json['timestamp'],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id' : id,
      'stock_id' : stock.toMap(),
      'product_id' : product.toMap(),
      'cnt' : cnt,
      'del' : del,
      'timestamp' : timestamp,
    };
  }
}

And i have this database function:
  Future<List<StockProduct>> getStockProducts() async {
    Database db = await _databaseService.database;

    var stockProdcuts = await db.query('stock_product');
 
    List<StockProduct> stockProdcutList = stockProdcuts.isNotEmpty ? stockProdcuts.map((c) => StockProduct.fromMap(c)).toList() : [];
    
    return stockProdcutList;
  }

My problem is when i run getStockProducts() nothing is returned and i dont get an error. It stops at .toList().
stockProducts.length is returning 3 (i have 3 stock_products) in the database.
I expect the function to return 3 Stock Products in a List
